# Error en archivos temporales en reconocimiento facial con python: ~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de reconocmiento facial con python y al momento en el que se deberían guardar las imagenes de mi rostro en una carpeta me salta el siguiente error:

> [ WARN:0] global C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-m8us58q4\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import cv2 as cv
import os

modelo = 'FotosLucio'
ruta1 = 'C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/Programación/Python/Reconocimiento facial/Reconocimientofacial1'
rutacompleta = ruta1+'/'+modelo

if not os.path.exists(rutacompleta):
    os.makedirs(rutacompleta)


ruidos = cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

camara = cv.VideoCapture(0)

id = 0

while True:
    respuesta, captura = camara.read()
    if respuesta == False:
        break
    grises = cv.cvtColor(captura, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    idcaptura = captura.copy()
    
    caras = ruidos.detectMultiScale(grises, 1.3, 5)

    for(x, y, e1, e2) in caras:
        cv.rectangle(captura, (x, y), (x+e1, y+e2), (255, 0 , 0), 2)
        rostrocapturado = idcaptura[x:x+e1,y:y+e2]
        rostrocapturado = cv.resize(rostrocapturado, (160, 160), interpolation=cv.INTER_CUBIC)
        cv.imwrite(rutacompleta+'/imagen_{}.jpg'.format(id), rostrocapturado)
        id = id + 1

    cv.imshow("Resultado rostro", captura)

    if id == 351:
        break

camara.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Espero su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de OpenCV usás?

Comment: Mi versión de OpenCV es la 4.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad no es un error, es una advertencia (*warning*). Esto se ha reportado varias veces en el repositorio en [GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/198) (y también en [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888878/cv2-warn0-terminating-async-callback-when-attempting-to-take-a-picture)).

Las opciones que tenés, según lo que reportan, son:

- Pasar como argumento la preferencia de API [`CAP_DSHOW`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294dab6ac3effa04f41ed5470375c85a23504) al invocar a `cv.VideoCapture`:

```
cv.VideoCapture(0, cv.CAP_DSHOW)
```

o,

- Si estás en Windows, abrir cmd y escribir:

```
setx OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF 0
```

o, como última opción,

- Usar la versión 3.4.2.16 de OpenCV.

Comment: Intenté con todas las opciones y ya no me da la advertencia anterior pero las imagenes que debería sacar no las guarda en la carpeta. El programa inicia y finaliza sin ningún error pero crea la carpeta y no guarda las imagenes allí. Alguna idea de cual podría ser el problema?

Comment: Justo edité el comentario porque me había expresado muy mal. Ahora si me expresé de la forma correcta. Disculpa

Comment: Ahí el problema ya es otro... Tenés que especificarlo en la pregunta (y también en el título) para que quede más claro.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Otra sugerencia: no alteres por completo el título de la pregunta, ya que en ese caso estás _boicoteándola_ (es una pregunta totalmente distinta en ese caso). Además, el título debe ser descriptivo: "problema al..." no proporciona un contexto inicial.

Comment: Te lo agradezco. Ya lo corregí. Lo mejor sería hacer otra pregunta?

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta tu problema, es mejor una nueva pregunta :)